# Keep getting error inserting data into SQL Server from C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm writing a simple program to insert data into a table. Keep getting this error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>   Additional information: ExecuteNonQuery: Connection property has not been initialized.

Code:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Server=ServerName;Database=byte;User=USR;Pwd=PSW;");

con.Open();
string INstring = "INSERT INTO BWDrfid(RFID,EmpNum) VALUES ('" + RFID + "', '" + EID + "')";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(INstring);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

con.Close();
```

Comment: You never set the `SqlCommand.Connection` property equal to your connection.

Comment: you aren't setting the connection anywhere.

Comment: might i suggest using a `using` block?

Comment: Are you sure the connection string is well formed? also which database are you connecting to?

Comment: Also I want to suggest: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well for starters you haven't attached a connection with your SqlCommand, and that is what the error is exactly telling you.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(INstring, con);
```

More importantly, **Parametrized your query**, you are open to SQL injection. Also consider enclosing your `SqlCommand` and `SqlConnection` object in `using` statement.

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Server=ServerName;Database=byte;User=USR;Pwd=PSW;"))
{
    con.Open();
    string INstring;
    INstring = "INSERT INTO BWDrfid(RFID,EmpNum) VALUES (@RFID, EID)";
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(INstring, con))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@RFID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = RFID);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@EID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = EID);
        //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EID", EID); //Or AddWithValue
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You are not connecting the *command* and the *connection*.  Use this overload instead:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(INstring, con);
```

Answer (score 2):

you are missing the connection  argument

you  can use this overload

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(INstring, con);
```

or  this one

```
sqlCommand.Connection = con;
```

[SqlCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thank you, sometimes I look at something for so long I miss the smallest things. I really appreciate your prompt response.